# How to detect when an Android device is attached via USB tethering and obtain it's interface name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking

I inherited a bash script that needs to detect the interface name of any Android device that is attached via USB tethering and then writes that interface name to another variable. Here's the existing code (simplified).

```
if [ -s /sys/class/net/enp0s20f0u3/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp0s20f0u3" > /var/tmp/myfile

elif [ -s /sys/class/net/enp0s20f0u5/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp0s20f0u5" > /var/tmp/myfile

elif [ -s /sys/class/net/enp6s0u1/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp6s0u1" > /var/tmp/myfile

elif [ -s /sys/class/net/enp0s20f0u4/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp0s20f0u4" > /var/tmp/myfile

elif [ -s /sys/class/net/enp0s20f0u6/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp0s20f0u6" > /var/tmp/myfile

elif [ -s /sys/class/net/enp0s20f0u10/operstate ]; then
    /usr/bin/echo "enp0s20f0u10" > /var/tmp/myfile
```

If a future Android device is given a different interface name, the code has to be hand modified after we find that the script didn't work. Obviously, this is a very poor implementation.

What is a better way to achieve the same results?

#### EDIT 1:

What I really mean is, How can this code be refactored so that every interface name does not need to be hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal situation? Rewrite that as a udev rule so that it triggers automatically on connection.  It will have to be evaluated after other rules so that any interface renaming has already happened by the time it gets evaluated (`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-x-local.conf` is probably the place to put it), but the basic rule should look similar to this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="rndis_host", ACTION=="add", RUN{program}+="/bin/sh -c 'echo $env{INTERFACE} > /var/tmp/myfile'"
```

The first four parts match the exact event generated when the device gets connected, more specifically:

- `SUBSYSTEM=="net"` matches networking devices
- `ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb"` matches only those networking devices that are connected via USB.
- `ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="rndis_host"` matches only USB devices that use the RNDIS host device driver (the standard one used by Android phones (and I think Windows and Blackberry too) for USB tethering.
- `ACTION=="add"` matches on the hotplug events only (so this only gets run when the device gets connected, though you could just as easily add a second similar rule matching on the "remove" action to  do something when the phone gets unplugged).

The final item adds a command to the queue of things that udev will invoke when the rule processing is done,.  In this case, it's adding a shell invocation that will write out the interface name to the desired location (udev itself will substitute the `$env{INTERFACE}` for the actual interface name).

I can't guarantee that that will work in all cases, but it at least seems to work for my Nexus 6P and should in theory work for most Android phones.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm not ready for such a big change. I was hoping to take a smaller step of simply refactoring the bash script. I may ultimately use udev rules, but this approach will impact a lot of other scripts. Implementing it will require more work and more testing than I have the time to do now. It may also break many things and lead to a chain reaction of more work. Then, there is also the aspect of implementing the ACTION=="remove" rule. I think I'm only ready for the small step of refactoring the bash script now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no signficance in the order, you might just loop through all the directories in `/sys/class/net/` until you find one that is up, and is not the loopback device:

```
for interface in /sys/class/net/*
do name=${interface##*/}  # just the final directory
   state=$(<$interface/operstate)   # read the file
   [ "$name" = lo ] && continue     # if lo continue to next
   [ "$state" = up ] || continue    # if not up continue to next
   echo $name >/var/tmp/myfile
   break                            # stop
done
```